# How can I know the default ciphersuite a server provides using Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming

If I am using Java to initiate SSL handshake with a server, Java has a set of enabled ciphersuites that will be offered during the handshake. This list will influence the server's choice. If I want to know what is the default choice for the serve, without being influenced by the client, can I do this? What shall I add in the client's list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'the default choice for the server without being influenced by the client'. The question has no meaning. The client supplies a list of cipher suites, the server chooses one, period.

Comment: Thanks. Does the order of the client ciphersuite list influence the server's choice ?

Comment: @user1810868 It isn't specified in [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/RFC/rfc2246.txt) how the server chooses. Particular implementations of SSL may behave in specific ways: for example, Java JSSE is specified to choose the strongest, although whether it really does so is another question.